# ASP.Net MVC IIS6 and ACL Errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6, acl

I have an asp.net mvc 3 app installed on IIS6 and I am getting ACL errors (401.3 errors) when trying to access it.  It is running as a virtual app under the default web.  I have gone through what I believe are the correct security setting on the respective folders.

I have given the Network Service and in IUSER_ users access to the root folder of the default web.  I have also given access to the microsoft.net, temp and system32 folders under c:\windows.

I still get the 401.3 error.  When I set the app to use both anonymous and windows authentication I get prompted for credentials.  Entering the credentials allows me to access the app.  This means that there is some file/folder that needs permissions.

So I used FileMon to see what was going on.  I hit the site and get the ACL error but I see no ACCESS DENIED errors in FileMon nor so I see any reference to the site itself.  It is like I never made a request.  (Yes I cleared my cache).

I am tapped out on what to do next.  Any suggestions on where to look to determine what resources needs permissions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was finally able to resolve the issue.  There was a permissions issue on the Microsoft.Net directory.  There were deny permissions being propagated to child directories for the Internet Users group even though that group had been granted access at a lower level to the resources that IIS needed to execute .Net code.

Answer (score 0):

In order for MVC to work on IIS6, you need to do some configuration changes in IIS.  Specifically, you should tell IIS to handle all request, in order to ensure that the .NET routing engine kicks in.

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/21/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx/

This is one of the best tutorials on getting MVC to work with IIS6.